# Global existence theorem for Ode

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We have the Cauchy problem:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x= f(t,x)\\ 
x(t_0)=x_0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
with $f: (\alpha,\beta) \rightarrow R^n$

$f$ locally Lipschitz continuous,
$f$ has at most a sublinear growth : $|f(t,x)| \le L_1+L_2|x|$

Using the local formulation of  the existence theorem applied repeatedly with initial values
$(t_k,x_k)$  ,  $\forall k=0,1...$

$a_k=b_k-t_k$  , $b_k > 0$

$ \delta_k = \min \{ a_k ; {b_k \over M_k} \} = \min \{ \beta - t_k ; {b_k \over {M_k}}\}$

$M_k=\max\{|f(t,x)|:x \in [t_k,\beta], |x-x_k|<= b_k\}$

$\forall t \in [a,b] $  , $\forall |x-x_k| \le b_k|$

From the sublinearity of $f$ we have:

$|f(t,x)| \le L_1+L_2|x|<= L_1 + L_2(|x|+b_k)$

We choose: $b_k=L_1 + L_2|x_k|$

${M_k \over b_k} = {1 \over b_k}\{\max{|f(t,x)|:x \in [t_k,\beta], |x-x_k|<= b_k}\}$
$\le  {1 \over b_k} (L_1 + L_2|x_k| + L_2b_k)=1+L_2 $

Can somebody explain me the next step?

If $\delta_k= {M_k \over b_k}$ it can't be $\delta_k = {M_k  \over b_k}$,cause in fact in this case we should have : $ \delta_k \ge {1 \over 1 + L_2}$ $\forall k$
and then $t_k \rightarrow +\infty$ absurdum (???)

So there exists $k : \delta_k= \beta-t_k$ and $t_{k+1} =t_k + \delta_k$

Comment: Maybe 'cause I found an evaluation of $\delta_k$ that doesn't depends on the initial data, so  I can choose any istant of time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

If $\forall k$  we have $\delta_k \neq \beta-t_k$  $\Rightarrow $   $t_k< \beta$
then $\delta_k \ge  \frac {b_k} M_k$ $\ge \frac 1 {1+2L}$ that doesn't depends on inital values

then $t_k \rightarrow \infty$

So there exists $\delta_k=\beta-t_k$ such that $t_{k+1}= x_k+\delta_k$